# How to deal with discontinuities in the Runge-Kutta algorithm?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to solve the following set of differential equations for plotting particle trajectories (using 4th order Runge-Kutta method):
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=-\Delta\left[\frac{2}{r}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}\right)\right]^{1/2}\left(r^2+a^2+\frac{2a^2}{r}\right)^{-1}$$
$$\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{2a^2}{r}\left(r^2+a^2+\frac{2a^2}{r}\right)^{-1}$$
where $\Delta=r^2+a^2-2r$ and $a$ is a constant. We require to plot the trajectory in the $r-\phi$ plane (or equivalently, in the $x-y$ plane with $x=\sqrt{r^2+a^2}\cos\phi$ and $y=\sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\phi$).

The above equations can also be written as a single differential equation as follows:
$$\frac{d\phi}{dr}=-\frac{2a}{r\Delta}\left[\frac{2}{r}\left(1+\frac{a^2}{r^2}\right)\right]^{-1/2}$$

**The difficulty I am facing in solving the problem is that when $\Delta=0$ (called horizons), $\dfrac{dr}{dt}$ and $\dfrac{dr}{d\phi}$ becomes zero, but $\dfrac{d\phi}{dt}$ remains finite there. For this reason, the trajectory has discontinuities at two values of $r$ when $\Delta=0$. The following is a plot of the trajectories for $a=0.8$ and the initial conditions $(r,\phi)=(8,0)$ at $t=0$:**

[image: plot]

In the figure, the axes are $x=\sqrt{r^2+a^2}\cos\phi$, $y=\sqrt{r^2+a^2}\sin\phi$, $\mu=1$ (already used in the equations) and the dashed lines correspond to the horizons ($\Delta=0$). Note that the behavior of the trajectory changes at the horizon.

**It would be very helpful if someone could suggest me how to deal with the discontinuities (shown in dashed lines) in the Runge-Kutta algorithm for the particle trajectories.**

Comment: what kind of behavior does the RK method have in this situation? did you see something peculiar?

Comment: @G.Gare At those locations where $\Delta=0$, the $\phi$-coordinate flips the direction and the particle moves inwards. But I don't know how to implement this in the code.

Comment: what if you integrate the original system for $(\dot r, \dot \phi)$?

Comment: As far as I can see, at the locations where $Δ=0$ the first DE is differentiable, so the approach is exponentially asymptotic. No trajectory will cross the circle. The continuation problem that you describe does not actually happen.

Comment: @G.Gare In that case, $dr/dt=0$ and $d\phi/dt$ is finite.

Comment: well that's what you want, no? you start revolving on the $\Delta = 0$ line ($r$ constant and $\phi$ makes you spin around). Indeed @LutzLehmann is right you shouldn't cross the dashed lines...

Comment: Yes, that's the problem that I am facing. The trajectory doesn't cross the $\Delta=0$ circle, whereas in reality it should flip the $\phi$ coordinate and move inwards as shown in the figure.